# Using Selenium to move slider handle with non-integer offset amount

Tags: java, selenium

I'm attempting to test moving a slider (using rc-slider: http://react-component.github.io/slider/) using Selenium. The issue is that based on the width of the slider and the range of values, sometimes the target offset is non-integer amount. If I convert the target offset to an int (seen in my code below), it sometimes ends up 1 value lower/higher than intended.

Unfortunately it looks like methods available in Actions (dragAndDropBy, moveByOffset, etc) only support ints as offset amounts. Is there another way I can move the slider handle to the correct offset, even it's a float and not an int?

```
private void setSingleValue(String boundSelector, Integer value) {
    if (value != null) {
        WebElement slider = this.webElement().findElement(By.className("rc-slider"));
        WebElement handle = slider.findElement(By.className(boundSelector));

        float valuePercentage = (float)value / this.maxValue;
        int sliderWidth = slider.getSize().getWidth();

        int xOffset;
        if (value == 0) { // move slider back to beginning
            xOffset = -this.maxValue;
        } else {
            xOffset = (int)(sliderWidth * valuePercentage); // converting to int here, but don't want to if possible
        }

        Actions action = new Actions(getWebDriver());
        action.dragAndDropBy(handle, xOffset, 0);
        action.build().perform();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am checking the [sliders](http://react-component.github.io/slider/examples/slider.html) and all of them have the integer positions so not sure why you need the float. Can you provide the sample where you will get the float value to be selected.

Comment: Sure. Say my slider is 176px wide, the range of values is between 0 and 250, and the desired value is 110. In this case, we calculate the pixel offset like this `176 * (110/250)`, which ends up with an offset of 77.44. The way rc-slider works, some intervals between 2 values are less than 1 pixel. So if I round down to 77px, the resulting slider value is 109. If I round up to 78px, the resulting value is 111.